# use struct to display image for certain length of time

Tags: swift, for-loop, struct, integer, uiimage

I want my swift code below to take the struct data and use in something like a for loop. The loop should take the arrayOne and use it for duration for how long the image should be displayed on imageview pic.  The Uiimage array should correspond to the int.So there are 2 images and two ints just make it so that they dispaly on the imageview pic for the int that matches there place in their respective arrays.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var pic = UIImageView()
    
    
    var somePics:[UIImage] = [ UIImage(named: "a.png")!,UIImage(named: "b.png")!]
    var emptyb = [UIImage]()
    var someInts:[Int] = [10, 20]

    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       Added(arrayOne: someInts, arrayTwo: emptyb)
        view.addSubview(pic)
        pic.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        pic.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        //for added.

    }


}


struct Added {
    var arrayOne: [Int]
    var arrayTwo: [UIImage]
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609280/how-to-merge-two-arrays-into-a-struct) question?

Comment: Right here was a related question but for audio only. But here you can reuse this for showing image. Check this answer here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494572/play-swift-sound-based-on-each-duration-of-i-time-in-array/63494875#63494875

Comment: Like in my answer above, you need to run timer and hide image when it out, after that check if this a last int in array, if not - run new timer. Do you need some clear example? or you will try to do it like in my example with timers above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully worked example. Check if it is all okay for you!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var pic = UIImageView()
    var somePics: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1")!, UIImage(named: "image2")!]
    var emptyb = [UIImage]()
    var someInts:[Int] = [5, 6]
    var currentIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(pic)
        pic.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        pic.backgroundColor = .yellow
        runGallery()
    }
    
    func runGallery() {
        guard !somePics.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        currentIndex = 0
        newTimerForIndex(index: 0)
    }
    
    func newTimerForIndex(index: Int) {
        let image = somePics[index]
        pic.image = image
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: Double(someInts[index]), repeats: false) { timer in
            if self.currentIndex + 1 < self.somePics.count {
                //RUN gallery for next image
                self.currentIndex += 1
                self.newTimerForIndex(index: self.currentIndex)
            } else {
                //STOP on last element
                self.pic.image = nil
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Added {
    var arrayOne: [Int]
    var arrayTwo: [UIImage]
}
```